# Posting a comment with a link to chat in chat results in wrong link

Tags: bug, chat

John Conde posted the following comment on [some question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736508/php-framework-why) (it's deleted now):

> This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). See [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and the rest of the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

But when posting that comment in chat the parser once again failed to properly parse the message. When pasting the following in chat:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736508/php-framework-why#comment20619470_14736508
```

The message was converted to:

> This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [Stack Exchange Api V2 Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). See don't ask and the rest of the faq. — John Conde 35 secs ago

As you can see both the link and the name of chat was converted to the wrong generic chat. So it looks like it is trying to be too smart again :-)